# UIButton is not adding on UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

here i am trying to add two button on **viewforprofileandsetting** view but below code is not working:

```
( UIView * )viewForProfileAndSettingButton 
{
    setingAndProfileView=[[ UIView alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,_listView.frame.size.height, _listView.frame.size.width, _listView.frame.size.height/4)];
    setingAndProfileView.backgroundColor=[ UIColor darkGrayColor ];
    profileViewButton=[[ UIButton alloc ]init];
    profileViewButton =[ UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    profileViewButton.backgroundColor=[ UIColor whiteColor ];
    [ profileViewButton setTitle:@" profile View" forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
   profileViewButton.frame=CGRectMake(setingAndProfileView.frame.origin.x+5, setingAndProfileView.frame.origin.y+10, setingAndProfileView.frame.size.width/2-50, setingAndProfileView.frame.size.height/2+10);

    settingButton=[[ UIButton alloc ]init];
    settingButton.backgroundColor=[ UIColor whiteColor ];
    settingButton=[ UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect ];

    settingButton.frame=CGRectMake(profileViewButton.frame.origin.x+profileViewButton.frame.size.width+10, setingAndProfileView.frame.origin.y+10, setingAndProfileView.frame.size.width/2-50, setingAndProfileView.frame.size.height/2+10);
    [ settingButton setTitle:@" setting View" forState:UIControlStateNormal ];

    [ setingAndProfileView addSubview:profileViewButton ];
    [ setingAndProfileView addSubview:settingButton ];

    return setingAndProfileView;
}
```

Comment: Where and how have you declared each of the above views/buttons? Also, please explain HOW the above code is not working, as in what is the expected and actual outcome.

Comment: Set y co-ordinate correct. if you set it to 0 or less then view height it will work good

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code:

1. How have you declared these views? Are they instance variables of the viewController class?
2. You only need to call either `[[UIButton alloc] init]` or `[ UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect ]`.
3. The frame for the buttons needs to be set with relation to the superview, hence no need to take it's frame into account.

Here's how it should look like (assuming the values have been declared):

```
-( UIView * )viewForProfileAndSettingButton 
{
    setingAndProfileView=[[ UIView alloc ]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,_listView.frame.size.height, _listView.frame.size.width, _listView.frame.size.height/4)];
    setingAndProfileView.backgroundColor=[ UIColor darkGrayColor ];

    profileViewButton =[ UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    profileViewButton.backgroundColor=[ UIColor whiteColor ];
    [ profileViewButton setTitle:@" profile View" forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
    profileViewButton.frame=CGRectMake(5, 10, setingAndProfileView.frame.size.width/2-50, setingAndProfileView.frame.size.height/2+10);

    settingButton=[ UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect ];
    settingButton.backgroundColor=[ UIColor whiteColor ];
    settingButton.frame=CGRectMake(profileViewButton.frame.origin.x + profileViewButton.frame.size.width+10, 10, setingAndProfileView.frame.size.width/2-50, setingAndProfileView.frame.size.height/2+10);
    [ settingButton setTitle:@" setting View" forState:UIControlStateNormal ];

    [ setingAndProfileView addSubview:profileViewButton ];
    [ setingAndProfileView addSubview:settingButton ];

    return setingAndProfileView;
}
```